# How to calculate heat and mass transfer rates from an enclosed box?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, convection, mass-transfer

I'd like to know if it's possible to calculate the heat and mass transfer rates from a small volume to the environment.

Let's assume there is a box with a small opening at the top. The air inside the box is hot and humid (65 °C and 100% relative humidity). The air outside the box is cooler and drier (25 °C and 50% relative humidity).

How should I proceed? I've tried using Fick's law of diffusion but the rate of transfer was too low. There must be something I am missing. I've thought about free convection but it does not fit for my situation I guess. Could Boussinesq equation be used?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

For modelling the rate of air flow through the opening, empirical relationships in the ASHRAE Fundamentals Handbook seem relevant here.

### Volumetric flowrate

Equation 37 on [page 25.13 of the 1997 version](https://archive.org/details/ASHRAEHANDBOOK1997/page/n503/mode/1up), section "Flow Caused by Thermal Forces" may be useful for calculating flow rate:

$$Q=C_D \cdot A \cdot \sqrt{2 \cdot g \cdot \Delta H_{NPL} \cdot (T_i - T_o)/T_i} $$

where:

$Q$ : airflow rate, [$\frac{m^3}{s}$]

$C_D$ : discharge coefficient for opening [$-$]

$A$ : Area of opening, [$m^2$]

$g$ : gravitational constant, $9.81 \space \frac{m}{s^2}$

$\Delta H_{NPL}$ : height from midpoint of lower opening to NPL (Neutral Pressure Level, "the height at which the interior and exterior pressures are equal"), [$m$]

$T_i$ : indoor temperature, [$K$] (assuming $T_i>T_o$)

$T_o$ : outdoor temperature, [$K$] (assuming $T_i>T_o$)

The value for $C_D$ that takes into account interfacial mixing of the bidirectional flow of air through the opening is Equation 38:

$$C_D={0.40}+{0.0045}|T_i - T_o|$$

### Density

Density can be calculated from equations 11, 22, and 27.

### Specific Enthalpy

The volumetric flow rate $Q$ and density, combined with the [enthalpy difference](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/hvac/41264-how-to-use-psychrometric-chart/) ($65^{\circ}C$ @ 100% RH vs. $25^{\circ}C$ @ 50% RH) of two points on [this psychrometric chart on page 6.11](https://archive.org/details/ASHRAEHANDBOOK1997/page/n102/mode/1up), should permit you to calculate heat transfer out of the building via this natural convection air flow, assuming air pressure is near $101.325 \space {kPa}$.

If air pressure is not close to $101.325 \space {kPa}$, then the set of equations referenced by the Situation 3 table of the "NUMERICAL CALCULATION OF MOIST AIR PROPERTIES" section on page [page 6.10](https://archive.org/details/ASHRAEHANDBOOK1997/page/n101/mode/1up) can be used instead to calculate specific enthalpies as a function of dry-bulb temperature $t$, Relative humidity $\psi$, and absolute pressure $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a very rough start, one could assume a convective column of hot air with a diameter of a bit smaller than the box opening that accelerates up.

This column can be assumed randomly to take advantage of the buoyancy of a layer 2*d thick, d being the diameter of the opening, for its propellant force. 
The convection formula is $$ q = h_c A dT  $$

But establishing $ \ h_c$ is not easy.

This will be our model. we can measure the temperature above this opening at different heights and adjust the parameters of our assumption